# Hide particular feeds from Google Reader main article stream

Tags: google-reader

I'm using Google Reader and I'm looking for a way to hide some feeds from my stream of all unread articles.

Basically if you subscribe to a feed all its new articles appear in the list. I don't want all feeds to appear there. Is there a way to accomplish this? I searched for such a functionality inside Google Reader itself and also through Google but couldn't come up with a good solution myself.

(Browser: Google Chrome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't selective choose which feeds are excluded from the "All Items" stream.

You can, however, tag feeds with multiple tags.

So, if you organize your feeds by topic, e.g.

- Technology
- Movie Stars
- Cooking

How about also organizing by importance? You can use tags like

- Read daily
- Read when I have nothing else to do
- Read only when desperate
- All Items except the feeds I don't care much about

Then just make sure you tag the feeds you *really* want to read in a stream with the same tag.

In your settings, you can change the Reader start page to be one of your tags.